# Replacing a filename problem?

Tags: vb6

Using VB6

In a folder, am having n number of text files, file names are like abc.mis-.txt, def.fin@.txt, so i want to rename the filenames like abcmis.txt, deffin.txt. I used a function for renaming.

Code

```
Dim filename3 As String
filename3 = Dir$(txtSourceDatabaseFile & "\*.txt", vbDirectory)
Do While filename3 <> ""
```

'Function for renaming

```
Dim strInput As String
Dim stroutput As String
Dim strChar As String
Dim intChar As Integer
Dim intLoop As Integer
strInput = filename3
For intLoop = 1 To Len(strInput)
strChar = Mid$(strInput, intLoop, 1)
intChar = Asc(strChar)
If ((intChar >= 48) And (intChar <= 57)) Or _
((intChar >= 65) And (intChar <= 90)) Or _
((intChar >= 97) And (intChar <= 122)) Or _
(intChar = 95) Then
stroutput = stroutput & strChar
End If
Next

Name txtSourceDatabaseFile & "\" & filename3 As txtSourceDatabaseFile & "\" & stroutput & ".txt"


filename3 = Dir$
Loop
```

Above Coding is working, the problem is am using while conditon, so it will rename all the txt files, It is giving a names likes

For Example.

```
The first time giving a fileaname as abc in "stroutput"
The second time giving a filename as abcdef in "Stroutput"
...,
```

It is adding a previous filename also, because am getting a filename in while loop itself.

How to modify my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your function into a VB6 function that takes the filename as an argument and returns the new one, eg :

```
Private Function GetTextOnlyFileName(ByVal strOldName as String) As String
    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim strChar As String
    Dim intChar As Integer
    Dim intLoop As Integer
    For intLoop = 1 To Len(strOldName)
        strChar = Mid$(strOldName, intLoop, 1)
        intChar = Asc(strChar)
        If ((intChar >= 48) And (intChar <= 57)) Or _
            ((intChar >= 65) And (intChar <= 90)) Or _
            ((intChar >= 97) And (intChar <= 122)) Or _
            (intChar = 95) Then
        strTemp = strTemp & strChar
        End If
    Next
    GetTextOnlyFileName = strTemp
End Function
```

Then use something like this this to get the new filename :

```
Do While filename3 <> ""
    strNewName = GetTextOnlyFileName(strFileName3)
    'next rename the file to strNewName


    'get name of next file
Loop
```

However, what do you want to happen if two different source filenames give the same renamed one? Eg, currently abc@def.txt and ab@cd@ef.txt would return the same thing.

Your code is currently appending the filename to the previous one because you're reusing the same variables again and again in your loop without clearing the prior values. My function will work, but you could just add the line strOutPut = "" after the line strInput = filename3 and that should work too.